# Strategies or patterns for dynamic editing of viewmodel metadata in MVC3 and MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having a royal time delegating rote view generation to runtime and a rich view model. This move away from the dynamic compilation of richer Razor views has the drawback of requiring frequent rebuilds to play with small view model changes though.

What are my options for a more dynamic viewmodel/metadata meeting than the good old POCO data annotation attributes on my view model? The most obvious is a complete custom metadata provider that sources model metadata from a file or database, but I'm asking this question to get some ideas for other approaches. Maybe dynamically compiled POCO's, or a scripting engine?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with all of this?

Comment: @EricJ. I'm primarily trying to reduce my dependency on requiring a build for viewmodel metadata changes.

Answer (score 1):

The entire purpose of a View Model is to create a strongly typed model.  What you want to do cannot be done with strong typing, so using a View Model is pointless.

Either put up with having to recompile, or use ViewData for your data.

I'm a little unsure how it is you plan to make view model changes without recompiling anyways.. your controller needs to know about the ViewModel and if it changes, it will throw runtime exceptions.

Comment: It is primarily model metadata I wish to manage dynamically, not the view model itself. BTW, Razor views are strongly typed yet don't require explicit or manual recompilation, so this is not impossible.

Comment: @ProfK - Razor views are strongly typed to a pre-compiled view model via generics.  Because the View is compiled dynamically, the type it's based on must already be compiled.

Comment: I only really want to have dynamic metadata, which is achievable. I was just checking for possible alternatives to a custom metadata provider. I suppose not.